# How to store current locale date and time in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-cursor

..and later retrieve and show them as Strings?

I'm asking the user some input and I want to store both the date (i.e., day, month and year) and the time (i.e., the hour of the day) this input was submitted. Each submission is then saved in my SQlite database, and later retrieved from a `RecyclerView`.

I'm facing two problems at least. Right now I set up two `TEXT` fields in the database, `FIELD_DATE` and `FIELD_TIME`, where I'd like to store the string representation of date & time, in a format depending on the Android user locale.

From what I've read, the `android.text.format.DateFormat` should help me. So I set:

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getActivity());
java.text.DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getActivity());
```

Now I think I should call [`format(Date d)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) on both objects to get my string, but I don't know where do I get this `Date` object - don't even know if my two lines are correct. So:

- How to get a string representation of current date & time, based on the user defined (at OS level) locale?

That said (asked), I wonder if two fields for date & time are really what I'm looking for. As said, at the end I would like to show a `RecyclerView` reading the database. In that I will also need to filter out entries based on date, i.e.

> Entries referring to last week // last month // All
>   entries

So I'm also asking:

- Is a two-text-fields pattern the right choice to store date & time, given the need to easily filter out entries belonging to, say, last week? Should I better have separate columns for day, month and year?
- How to query the database to have only last week rows, given the `FIELD_DATE` / `FIELD_TIME` structure (or any other better structure you can suggest)?

I'm quite stuck on these three questions.

---

**Edit**: finally came up with how to get the strings I wanted at first, it was as simple as instantiating a new `Date` object:

```
Date d = new Date();
String date = DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getActivity()).format(d);
String time = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getActivity()).format(d);
```

Now I have both the needs to display these strings (which is quite simple, as they are already formatted) and to apply some filter to the db, like entries belonging to last week (which, in turn, would be quite simple with current time in millis since 1970). What to do?

Comment: I'm storing it in string format in my current project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to run complex queries such as find all records from last week, I would recommend storing a timestamp in an integer instead. A timestamp is expressed as the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (Jan 1, 1970). It makes it easy to make queries on exact date and time ranges.
The timestamp is easily found from e.g. System.currentTimeMillis().

The other approach would be to use sqlite's built in date type, but I would personally choose the timestamp approach.
Is there any reason you would want to store it in the current locale's format in the first place? If you are displaying the date to the user you're likely better of formatting the timestamp into a date when displayed, using one of the many date features of Java and android such as java.util.Calendar, java.util.Date, android.text.SimpleDateFormat etc.

As an example, you could run this code to get the timestamp of the start of this month:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND,  0);

long startOfThisMonth = now.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Just edited my question. I was happy with those strings because I need to show them to the user. I see how I could store `TimeInMillis` and query the db. But given this `long`, how could I later format it into a String, locale-based, human-readable representation? I miss this simple step.

Comment: It's much better to store them as timestamps and convert to human readable at the time when they are displayed. There are countless utilities to convert millis into locale specific strings, for example http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html that has a format method taking a Date, and Date has a constructor taking a milis.  If you persist on using strings in your database you will find it very difficult to make meaningful queries.

Comment: I will try as soon as possible. Meanwhile, do you think it would be useless to store both strings (to show) and milliseconds time (to query db)?

Comment: That seems completely redundant as it's trivial to convert timestamps to strings when needed. 
It would just cause extra effort when storing items. 

It would also cause problems if the user changes language (the latter being yet another reason not to store locale specific strings in the database) as the database would contain strings in the language used when the item was stored. 
There is simply no good reason to store dates as strings.

Comment: Now that I've tried I can say it is *really* trivial. Thank you very much, I was confused because I kept thinking about strings.